# Can I define different number for map and reduce slots for each node?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to know if I can define different number of slots for each node in hadoop cluster.
for ex: tasktracker1 :  2 map and 2 reduce
        tasktracker2 :  1 map and 1 reduce
        and so on...

Or I have to set number of slots for all nodes in the cluster

thanks so much,,

Note: I use hadoop version : 1.2.1 as it is the latest stable version but if there is any version can do that please tell me about

Comment: What hadoop version?

Comment: basically version 1.2.1 but if this feature can be in any version please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` and `mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum`. They're both set in `mapred-site.xml`.

There are [many configuration parameters](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) to play with in the configuration for map reduce jobs in hadoop. Some depend on the version you're using.

Comment: but can i set  mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum and mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum for each node"tasktracker" or it just set for the whole the cluster "all the nodes", I use version 1.2.1 as it is the latest stable version

Comment: Setting it in the file I mentioned is site-specific. I believe it means that's only limiting the machine it's set on. Give it a try.